# php code to display rows in two different display

Tags: php, html, css

**I create two design to display news .**

**first DIV** Display BIGGER images and Separate css class and display only two rows.

**Second DIV** Display Smaller images and Separate css class and display five rows..

**I select rows in asc order from query.
my query is = `select * from news order by priority asc.`**

**My Only Need is TO Display two rows in First div and then display another rows in Second DIV.**

**IS This is possible using if else or any other condition...how to do this.........**

but keep all div tag as it is bcoz of page design purpose......

```
<!-- FIRST DIV -->
    <div class="post">
          <div class="buffer">
           <?php foreach($top2 as $top){    ?>
            <div class="content"> <a href="detail.html"><img src="bhaskarcms/uploads/<?php echo $top['photo']; ?>" style="width:285px; height:100px;" /></a>
              <h2><a href="detail.html"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($top['headline']); ?></a></h2>        
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
             <!--<p class="details2"><a href="#">8 Comments</a> / <a href="#">Read More</a></p>-->
          </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- end post -->

<!-- SECOND DIV -->
        <!-- begin post -->
        <div class="post">  
          <div class="buffer">
          <?php foreach($top2 as $top){ ?>
            <div class="content1"><a href=""><img src="bhaskarcms/uploads/<?php echo $top['photo']; ?>" /></a>
              <h2><a href=""><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($top['headline']); ?></a></h2>        
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end post -->
```

Comment: if you use `<?php foreach($top2 as $top){    ?>` you display 2 time all $top2 element, it s your problem ?
In this case, different option, 1st create 2 array $top2big and $top2small and make two different foreach, 2 nd use `for` and fix a limit `for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {` and `for ($i = 3; $i <= 10; $i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Assuming your `$top2` array has standard numerical/sequential keys, then:

```
$split = 2;
for($i = 0; $i < $split; $i++) {
   ... print $top2[0] and $top2[1]
}

for ($i = $split; $i < count($top2); $i++) {
   ... print the rest of the rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [**array_slice()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
<!-- FIRST DIV -->
<div class="post">
<div class="buffer">
    <?php $arr = array_slice($top2, 0, 2) ?>
    <?php foreach($arr as $top){    ?>
        <div class="content"> <a href="detail.html"><img src="bhaskarcms/uploads/<?php echo $top['photo']; ?>" style="width:285px; height:100px;" /></a>
            <h2><a href="detail.html"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($top['headline']); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!--<p class="details2"><a href="#">8 Comments</a> / <a href="#">Read More</a>   </p>-->
</div>
</div>
<!-- end post -->

<!-- SECOND DIV -->
<!-- begin post -->
<div class="post">
<div class="buffer">
    <?php $arr = array_slice($top2, 2) ?>
    <?php foreach($arr as $top){ ?>
        <div class="content1"><a href=""><img src="bhaskarcms/uploads/<?php echo $top['photo']; ?>" /></a>
            <h2><a href=""><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($top['headline']); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a count that you increment in the foreach loop,  then break when its over two:

`<!-- FIRST DIV -->
    <div class="post">
          <div class="buffer">
           <?php 
            $rowCount = 0;
            foreach($top2 as $top){    ?>
            <div class="content"> <a href="detail.html"><img src="bhaskarcms/uploads/<?php echo $top['photo']; ?>" style="width:285px; height:100px;" /></a>
              <h2><a href="detail.html"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($top['headline']); ?></a></h2>

            </div>
            <?php
               $rowCount++;
               if($rowCount > 2){
                  break;
               }
             } ?>
             <!--<p class="details2"><a href="#">8 Comments</a> / <a href="#">Read More</a></p>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- end post -->`